# fatal error with many other in my android development project

Tags: android, xml, swing, sqlite

As i'm working with a project bus routes systems....
even i'm new to android programming.
but when i click my app it says :unfortunately it stopped...

please help me clear my errors... and even none of the tables are created in my database...

see this site:

[bus routes android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15813235/bus-routes-android-project?noredirect=1#comment22491196_15813235)

thanks in advance

```
04-04 14:14:43.700: D/AndroidRuntime(868): Shutting down VM
04-04 14:14:43.700: W/dalvikvm(868): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bus/com.example.bus.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at com.example.bus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: Do you use jar? You get the error, because of your app cant find it

Comment: plse, post your manifest file xml and Activity code. be sure that you added your Activity there

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-04 14:14:43.720: E/AndroidRuntime(868):  at com.example.bus.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
```

Simply check MainActivity.java, line 44 - you most likely try to use uninitialized variable there

Comment: yea in that line i declared   db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
nw it says javadoc is nt attached